# How to add a jar dependency which WAS NOT BUILT with maven to a project that IS BUILT with maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, artifact

I have two projects in Java, one is built using IntelliJ, the other is built using maven. The goal is simple, I want to use the artefact (a jar file) compiled with IntelliJ within the maven project, that is, I want to use the compiled code from artefact (built with IntelliJ) as a library for my maven project.

I added the following to the maven's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.plegeus</groupId>
    <artifactId>AmongUs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/deps/AmongUs.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Although I am unsure how much use properties like groupId and artifactId are since that project (the IntelliJ project) was not built using maven...

when I enter

```
mvn clean verify
```

everything seems fine, though, upon entering

```
java -jar target/benchmarks.jar
```

I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/plegeus/amongus/data/Image
    at org.plegeus.MyBenchmark.<init>(MyBenchmark.java:47)
```

(the Image class is a class from the first IntelliJ project which I want to use in the second maven project.)

So the question really is, how to add any arbitrary jar file (artefact) to a maven project? The method I currently use apparently is deprecated as well, because of `<scope>system</scope>`.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by built using IntelliJ?

Comment: When starting a new project, don’t select gradle or maven, but intellij

Comment: Don’t use system scope. Install the jar locally instead

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `deploy:deploy-file` command on the jar which is not in maven. Once the artifacts are generated, it can be added in the maven project.

The deploy:deploy-file mojo is used primarily for deploying artifacts, which were not built by Maven. The project's development team may or may not provide a POM for the artifact, and in some cases you may want to deploy the artifact to an internal remote repository. The deploy-file mojo provides functionality covering all of these use cases, and offers a wide range of configurability for generating a POM on-the-fly. Additionally, you can specify what layout your repository uses. The full usage statement of the deploy-file mojo can be described as:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file://C:\m2-repo \
                   -DrepositoryId=some.id \
                   -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                   [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                   [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                   [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                   [-Dversion=1.0] \
                   [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                   [-Dclassifier=test] \
                   [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                   [-DgeneratePom.description="My Project Description"] \
                   [-DrepositoryLayout=legacy]
```

Refer : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html#the-deploy-deploy-file-mojo

Comment: Thank you, sadly, it did not resolve the issue, I get the same exact error, what exactly am I supposed to do with the generate files (stored in m2-repo)?